# (OpenGL) CubeMap isn't drawn

Tags: opengl

I have a problem with cube maps in OpenGL. When I try to draw a cube map, it is shown black:

(I can't post images. It is shown a black cube with perspective distorsion)

Shaders are ok because the cube is drawn with perspective distorsion, and when I use this fragment shader, it is clear that shaders were loaded:
(I can't post images. It is shown a degraded cube from black to red)

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 direction;
out vec4 outcolor;

uniform samplerCube sampler;

void main() {
    outcolor = vec4(direction.x, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Cube map vao is ok obviously (the cube is shown).

Maybe the error is in the texture cube map loaded. Here is the code:

```
GLboolean load_bmp_data(LPCSTR path, char **data, GLuint *datapos, GLuint *width, GLuint *height, GLuint *bitsperpixel) {
    GLuint size = 0;

    load_raw_file(path, data, &size); // It was correctly writen (100% ok)
    if(NULL == *data) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error loading BMP image data from file '%s'.\n", path);
        return GL_FALSE;
    }

    if('B' != (*data)[0] || 'M' != (*data)[1]) {
        fprintf(stdout, "This image loader can only load BMP images.\n");
        free_raw_file(*data);
        return GL_FALSE;
    }

    *datapos       = *((GLuint *)(&(*data)[0x0A]));
    *width         = *((GLuint *)(&(*data)[0x12]));
    *height        = *((GLuint *)(&(*data)[0x16]));
    *bitsperpixel  = *((GLuint *)(&(*data)[0x1C])) & 0x0000FFFF;

    if(24 != *bitsperpixel) {
        fprintf(stdout, "This BMP image loader only supports loading 24 bits images.\n");
        free_raw_file(*data);
        return GL_FALSE;
    }

    return GL_TRUE;
}

void free_bmp_data(char *data) {
    free_raw_file(data);
}

GLboolean load_cube_map(cubemap_t *cubemap, LPCSTR dir, LPCSTR vertpath, LPCSTR fragpath) {
    vec3 vertices[36];
    GLuint vbo = 0;
    GLboolean noerror = GL_TRUE;
    char *path = NULL;
    char names[6][11] = {"right.bmp", "left.bmp", "top.bmp", "bottom.bmp", "front.bmp", "back.bmp"};
    unsigned int size = 0;
    GLuint i = 0;

    char *data = NULL;
    GLuint datapos = 0;
    GLuint width = 0;
    GLuint height = 0;
    GLuint bitsperpixel = 0;

    load_cube_positions(vertices, 1.0);

    // Generating buffer
    // ... Here I create the vertex buffer object and the vertex array object
    // ...

    // Loading shaders
    // Here I load the shaders from files

    // Loading faces
    glGenTextures(1, &cubemap->texture);
    if(0 == cubemap->texture) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error creating a texture object for cube map.\n");
        return GL_FALSE;
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemap->texture);

    size = strlen(dir); // dir = "shaders/cubemap/"
    path = malloc(size + 10);
    if(NULL == path) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error allocating dynamic memory for cube map paths.\n");
        return GL_FALSE;
    }
    strcpy(path, dir);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        strcpy(path + size, names[i]);
        if(GL_TRUE != load_bmp_data(path, &data, &datapos, &width, &height, &bitsperpixel)) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Error loading BMP data for cube map at '%s'.\n", path);
            return GL_FALSE;
        } // It doesn't fail, so data were loaded correctly
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data+datapos);
        free_bmp_data(data);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
    return GL_TRUE;
}
```

I think that the possible error isn't in the 'load_bmp_data' function because I can load a 2D image with this function and it works perfectly

The code that draws the cube map:

```
void draw_cube_map(const cubemap_t *cubemap, const mat4 *rotate, const mat4 *projection) {
    mat4 matrix = *rotate;
    translate_mat4(&matrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f); // Matrices functions are OK (100%)

    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glUseProgram(cubemap->shader);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(cubemap->model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)matrix.elements);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(cubemap->proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)projection->elements);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(cubemap->shader, "sampler");
    glUniform1i(loc, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemap->texture);

    glBindVertexArray(cubemap->vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
}
```

Comment: What are the sizes of the images? Are they all the same size, and square?

Comment: Also, are you setting `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` somewhere, or generating mipmaps? Otherwise your texture will not be mipmap complete.

Comment: All images sizes are 256x256. Yes, I set GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to GL_LINEAR

Answer (score 0):

Usually black texture means you have no texture mapped to your buffer or bad UVs.

Hard to tell for sure without spending exhaustive reading but it looks like you are mixing up two different things here that are not compatible. You could render a big cube and it can work like that, but then you should just be loading one texture and mapping one texture. Just like rendering a regular cube except you are doing it from the inside. You also have to make sure you are inside the cube not accidentally outside since you have face culling on - and that your winding order is correct.

http://mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=13

This tutorial explains how to get a cubemap going quickly and easily.

Comment: The face culling is not the problem, because the cube is draw perfectly. When I draw the "uv" (withmentioned fragment shader), It is seen than the faces drawn are the inside faces, so it can't be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer (but I don't understand it):

I had to set the filter method:

```
glTerParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTerParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

It can be GL_NEAREST or whatever. Thank you

Comment: `GL_LINEAR` should work too. You'll just have to either create mipmaps, or set a filter method that does not use mipmaps.

Comment: It can be GL_NEAREST or **whatever**. This includes GL_LINEAR :D

Comment: No, not whatever. The default for `MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, which is the reason it did not work in the first place. Any of the values needing mipmaps will not work if you don't create mipmaps, and if the texture is minified.